# Handle Google Service Exception (C#)

Tags: c#, google-search-api

I am developing a program to download images of 1000 words by querying Google Images search. However randomly after 100 to 200 downloads, the exception below is raised:

> An exception of type 'Google.API.GoogleServiceException' occurred in
>   GoogleSearchAPI.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: You could start by catching the exception...

Comment: I have used Try, Catch method but i don't know what should i write in catch block to handle Google Service Exception.

Comment: How do you want to handle the exception? What do you want to happen once the exception gets thrown?

Comment: @RogerWilliam i want to skip exception. I have used "Continue" but its not solving problem. Once exception occurs it kept occurring for next words.

Comment: Maybe because: For CSE users, the API provides 100 search queries per day for free. If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the Developers Console. Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview